# How to change state by clicking on button in inherited module

Tags: odoo

I Created a new module and inherited stock.picking module.In that added Accepted state between ready-to transfer and transfer state in warehouse. and a accept Button in header. 
while clicking on accept button ,function is executing but state is not changing to accepted state.other functions of existing module are working correctly.

I added new accept selection field in existing module. i.e stock.picking
.py file

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.exceptions import except_orm, Warning, ValidationError
import logging

class inventory_button_action(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'stock.picking'



def execute_accept_button(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.info('######### Executed 11111 ########')
    self.change_state_accept(cr, uid, ids, context=context)

def change_state_accept(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking')
    obj.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'accept'},context=context)

    log.info('######### Executed 2222 ########')

xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="inventory_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">inventory_status_form</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='do_enter_transfer_details']" position="before">
                        <button string="Accept" name="execute_accept_button" type="object" attrs="{'invisible':['|', ('state', 'in', ('draft','cancel','waiting','confirmed','partially_available','accept','done'))]}"/>
                    </xpath>


            </field>
        </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

in stock.picking module

```
_columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Reference', select=True, states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, copy=False),
        'origin': fields.char('Source Document', states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, help="Reference of the document", select=True),
        'backorder_id': fields.many2one('stock.picking', 'Back Order of', states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, help="If this shipment was split, then this field links to the shipment which contains the already processed part.", select=True, copy=False),
        'note': fields.text('Notes'),
        'move_type': fields.selection([('direct', 'Partial'), ('one', 'All at once')], 'Delivery Method', required=True, states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, help="It specifies goods to be deliver partially or all at once"),
        'state': fields.function(_state_get, type="selection", copy=False,
            store={
                'stock.picking': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, ctx: ids, ['move_type'], 20),
                'stock.move': (_get_pickings, ['state', 'picking_id', 'partially_available'], 20)},
            selection=[
                ('draft', 'Draft'),
                ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
                ('waiting', 'Waiting Another Operation'),
                ('confirmed', 'Waiting Availability'),
                ('partially_available', 'Partially Available'),
                ('assigned', 'Ready to Transfer'),('accept','Accepted'),
                ('done', 'Transferred'),
                ], string='Status', readonly=True, select=True, track_visibility='onchange')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a browse record `stock.picking` to save a value.
When you write `stok_obj.state = 'accept'` you have just change instance value nothing will be saved in the database (available since odoo-8).
To change `state` to `accept` you can use `write` function:

**openerp**:

```
def execute_accept_button(self, cr, uid, ids, *args):

    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'accept'})
    return True
```

**Odoo**:

```
@api.multi
def execute_accept_button(self):

    self.write({'state': 'accept'})
    return True
```

Comment: I tried it, still its not working. when i m changing in database from assign to accept then only it is changing.

Comment: @lipika return `True` after changing the state, I added just the needed lines.I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
def chnage_state_accept(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'accept'},context=context)
    return <<return value if needed>>
```

Comment: I tried it, still its not working. when i m changing in database from assign to accept then only it is changing.

Comment: first of all, i would like to thank u for responding quickly

Comment: Can you share the code where you added the new state 'accept'?

Comment: in stock.picking class of stock.py file, i added accept selection field in columns.

Comment: can you share that exact code where you added the new state. Also are you using Odoo new api or old api?